# binary ofstream::read()ing integer: expected endianness issue, but not getting it

Tags: c++

I use the following code to write out an integer on my Windows machine:

```
std::ofstream f("data.bin", ios::out  | ios_base::binary);
int nI = 65450;
f.write((char*)&nI, sizeof(int));
f.close();
```

I look at data.bin in a hex editor and see it is written in the same order that the memory is laid out for integer (AA FF 00 00)

I am then using the following to read it in on a Linux machine and on a Solaris Sparc 10 machine:

```
std::ifstream f2("data.bin", ios::in  | ios_base::binary);
int nI2 = 0;
f2.read((char*)&nI2, sizeof(int));
cout << "Read integer " << nI2 << std::endl;
f2.close();
```

As both Linux and Solaris are Big Endian, I expected the result to be AAFF, i.e. 43775.  However, I get varying results.  On Linux, the integer output is 65450, but on Solaris it is -1426128896.

As it turns out, -1426128896 is FFFFFFFFAAFF0000, but that is as far I can begin to understand this.

So, can someone please explain why I am getting the results that I am?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "both Linux and Solaris are Big Endian" - who told you that? It depends on the processor.

Comment: Your assumption of endianness per **OS** is potentially wrong, and your assumption of big-endian layout of a 32-bit `int` is *definitely* wrong. A 32-bit value `AA FF 00 00` interpreted as big-endian is 0xAAFF0000, not 0xAAFF. Mike's answer describes this and more, and should seriously be read over a few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> both Linux and Solaris are Big Endian

Endianness is a property of the processor, not the operating system. Both Linux and Solaris are little-endian on a little-endian architecture (such as Intel x86/x64) and big-endian on a big-endian architecture (such as Sparc).

So, if your Linux platform is little-endian, you'd expect to get back the same result written by Windows - as you do.

> I expected the result to be AAFF

Looking at the four bytes that were written to the file, you'd expect a big-endian interpretation of them to give `0xaaff0000`, not `0xaaff`, which (reinterpreted as a 32-bit signed value) gives the large negative value you see.

(That's assuming that Solaris for Sparc also uses 32-bit `int` values. The size of `int` is something else that can vary from machine to machine.)

Comment: +1 adding more fun than a human being should be allowed to have, a SPARC x64 can also access data in little-endian if properly configured. Nice answer, btw.

Comment: Indeed.  I used the script [here](http://serverfault.com/a/163493) to determine that my Linux box is little endian, the solaris one is big endian.